# Unable to fetch value from selectbox to servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

Trying to submit checked selectbox value(on at a time) along with textbox value to a servlet;here is my code(jsp) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function search(){
document.f2.action="/InfoUser/SearchBox";
document.f2.submit();
}
</script>

<form name="f2">
<div align="right">
<select id="select" name="select" style="color:#2D7EE7">
<option> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ----------- </option>
<option value="a">A</option>
<option value="b">B</option>
<option value="c">C</option>
</select> 
<input type="text" name="search" style="color:#2D7EE7">
<input type="submit" value="Search" onclick="search()">
</div>
</form>
```

and in the servlet : I have written

```
String[] select = request.getParameterValues("select");
String search = request.getParameter("search");
```

Unable to fetch the value in servlet,am I missing some javascript/jquery script to get the value in servlet & how I can use it with the help of `JSTL`.Any rectification if I'm going wrong .....feel free to comment,will be welcome.

Comment: what is f2?? is it your form id ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change your form:

```
<form action="/InfoUser/SearchBox">
    <div align="right">
        <select id="select" name="select" style="color:#2D7EE7">
            <option> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; -----------</option>
            <option value="a">A</option>
            <option value="b">B</option>
            <option value="c">C</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="search" style="color:#2D7EE7">
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </div>
</form>
```

Or:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function search(){
        document.f2.action="/InfoUser/SearchBox";
        document.f2.submit();
    }
</script>

<form name="f2">
    <div align="right">
        <select id="select" name="select" style="color:#2D7EE7">
            <option> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ----------- </option>
            <option value="a">A</option>
            <option value="b">B</option>
            <option value="c">C</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="search" style="color:#2D7EE7">
        <input type="submit" value="Search" onclick="search()">
    </div>
</form>
```

You are missing the name of the form and in your javascript you are trying to set the action on non-existing form.

In servlet you have to do:

```
String select = request.getParameter("select");
String search = request.getParameter("search");
```

You won't be able to use: `String[] select = request.getParameterValues("select");` unless your select element will have `multiple="true"`.

Comment: I go for your 2nd answer,but still ,unable to fetch the values...any guess why ?

Comment: Did you restart the server after changes? Also try the first code block, it really makes no sense to use javascript to submit the form where is no need to do so.

Comment: thanks a ton,now I 'm using these values in a class like : "select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from info where '"+request.getAttribute("select")+"' like '%"+request.getAttribute("search")+"%' order by serialNo asc limit " + offset + ", " + noOfRecords;" -- and I'm getting error in this line. Could you take a look of it.

Comment: it's in written in a class,and getting NullPointerException

Comment: At which point you are getting the NPE? `request.getAttribute("select")` can be used in the class which extends HttpServlet and overrides it's appropriate methods which takes the HttpServletRequest as a parameter. In order to use request in other class you have to pass it to that other class. Pass it through the method parameter or constructor argument. Or just get the values in a servlet and pass them to you class.

Comment: You might wanna ask specific question for this other issue you are facing and post some code of your servlet and class in which you are getting the error.